# Success Message for javascript function after copying

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some code that copies some text upon clicking the button using by using JavaScript. I want to make it so that if it gets copied, it should show a message for 3 seconds.

My code

```js
function copyToClipboard(element) {
    var $temp = $("<input>");
    $("body").append($temp);
    $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    $temp.remove();
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="i1" style="display: none;">Hello</p>
<button onclick="copyToClipboard('#i1')" class="btn btn-primary">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>Share
</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```js
function copyToClipboard(element) {
  var $temp = $("<input type='text'>");
  $("body").append($temp);
  $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $temp.remove();
  
  $('<div>Success!</div>').insertBefore('body').delay(3000).fadeOut();

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="i1" style="display: none;">Hello</p>
<button onclick="copyToClipboard('#i1')" class="btn btn-primary">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>Share
</button>
```

I've used `delay` method for displaying the message for 3sec.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I don't want alert after 3 seconds, I want alert to be displays for 3 seconds

Comment: Or I can also have Windows alert on copy

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to me that you have added the `copyToClipboard()` in some script tag which is below in your HTML.

Which definitely will not be available to be bind which HTML is getting rendered.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function copyToClipboard(element) {
    var $temp = $("<input>");
    $("body").append($temp);
    $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    $temp.remove();
    // SHOW SOME DIV as alert (static div hiddent in HTML)
    setTimeout(function(){
      // HIDE same DIV as alert
    }, 2000);
  }
</script>
<p id="i1" style="display: none;">Hello</p>
<button onclick="copyToClipboard('#i1')" class="btn btn-primary">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>Share
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function copyToClipboard(element) {
  var $temp =$("<input>");
  $("body").append($temp);
  $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
  if(document.execCommand("copy")){
    alert('Copied');  $temp.remove();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="i1" style="display: none;">Hallo</p>
<button onclick="copyToClipboard('#i1')" class="btn btn-primary">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>Share
</button>
```